# Add list values to queryset - Django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-queryset

I want to add a list object to the beginning of a queryset.

I have the following code for my ListAPIView:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    obj1 = Books.objects.most_read_offset()[:30]
    titles = Category.objects.most_publishes().values('title')
    categories = []
    for title in titles:   
        categories.append(title)
    categories.insert(0, {'title': 'Popular'})
    return chain(categories, obj1)
```

In my serializer, I use the following method to get the category url:

```
def get_category_url(self, obj):
    request = self.context['request']
    kwargs = {'slug': obj.category.slug}
    return api_reverse('category_detail_api', kwargs=kwargs,
                       request=request)
```

When I try to compile the code, I get an error saying: `'dict' object has no attribute 'category'`.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

**EDIT:**

This is what I would like my final result to look like:

```
[
    {
        "titles": "title_1", "title_2", "title_3",
    },
    {
        "id": 62,
        "category_url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/categories/just-because/",
        "slug": "XG84Jberu6",
    },
    {
        "id": 63,
        "category_url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/categories/something/",
        "slug": "YU65Zirvq7",
    },
]
```

Comment: It looks like your ``get_queryset`` function returns an iterator that returns three different types - First a dictionary, then str values, then Book values. Are you sure this is what you want?

Comment: @PenguinBrian I just added an edit to show what I would like my final result to look like. However we can make that happen :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JSON result has, quite frankly, a terrible structure and the framework tools will not help you create it easily. Back-track and consider a JSON structure like this instead where you don't mix different kinds of data in the same list:

```
{
    "titles": ["title_1", "title_2", "title_3"]
    "books": [
        {
            "id": 62,
            "category_url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/categories/just-because/",
            "slug": "XG84Jberu6",
        },
        {
            "id": 63,
            "category_url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/categories/something/",
            "slug": "YU65Zirvq7",
        }
    ]
}
```

And return this from a simple api_view:

```
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response

@api_view()
def combined_view(request):
    obj1 = Books.objects.most_read_offset()[:30]
    titles = Category.objects.most_publishes().values_list('title', flat=True)
    books_serializer = BookSerializer(obj1, context={'request': request}, many=True)  # this is your previous serializer
    return Response({
        "titles": titles,
        "books": books_serializer.data,
    })
```

If your `most_read_offset()` queryset doesn't include a `select_related('category')` you should add this as well since your fetching the category for all book objects in `get_category_url`.

Comment: Thank you for this. I am getting a `KeyError` for `request` in the line `request = self.context['request']`. Do you know why this is happening?

Comment: Updated answer to pass context